# Trigger Slug with symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine, slug

I am working with Symfony, and I am trying to slug some element of my database using Doctrine's extension Gedmo. The issue is that I initialize my database with a sql script, so I dont trigger the generation of the slug by Doctrine.

I would like to know if there is a clean way to generate it.
For instance:

```
public function getSlug(){
    if(empty($this->slug)){
       $this->slug=generateSlug();
    }
    return $this->slug;
;
```

I could not find any solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the sluggable readme: https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/sluggable.md

> Update 2013-08-19
>
> allow empty slug #807 regenerate slug only if set to null

so:

1. Fetch your entities
2. Set their slug to `null`
3. Flush

And you are done !